# Multiple Laravel Project on Same Single Server in VPS Provision

Tags: laravel-5, centos7, lamp

I have one VPS with operating system Centos 7.

I want to run multiple Laravel project on same sever so, how can I do that with LAMP server?

My single laravel project run perfectly but multiple laravel project are not working.